# Why doesn't std::regex_match return true with $ pattern?

Tags: c++, regex, exception, string-matching

With [std::regex_replace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace),
I can match the end of a word using "$" and then append additional characters.

```
std::cout << std::regex_replace("word",std::regex("$"),"s") << '\n';
//prints: words
```

Since the result was different than the original input, I assumed the regular expression had matched.

However,

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha;
std::cout << std::regex_match("word",std::regex("$")) << '\n';
//prints: false
```

**How can it be that the regular expression does not match, yet regex_replace was able to make a replacement?**

---

I also tried adding a `*` for 0 or more characters, but that threw an exception:

```
  std::cout << std::regex_match("word",std::regex("*$")) << '\n';
  std::cout << std::regex_replace("word",std::regex("*$"),"s") << '\n';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that regex_match will only successfully match a regular expression to an entire character sequence, whereas std::regex_search will successfully match subsequences.

You want `regex_search` for matching subsequences. `$` does not match the entirety of a non-empty string, but does match a (zero-length) substring of a non-empty string.